# WordPress, passing parameter via URL problem localhost vs webhost

Tags: php, wordpress, url, variables, parameter-passing

I am developing a simple WordPress base website for a friend. It is working fine on my laptop using MAMP to create a localhost environment but when I transfer the site to my webhost I run into a problem.

Running locally and on the web host a custom loop file generates URLs like this:
    http://bch.techzen.org/programme?month=May,2011

However, when I click on the link the behaviour varies:
- running locally the address bar shows *http://bch.techzen.org/programme?month=May,2011*
- running on the web the address bar is *http://bch.techzen.org/programme/?month=May,2011*

In the second example note the extra / preceding the ? mark, which is messing up the visibility of the $month variable to the loop.

The code on the two platforms is identical, both are running WP 3.1.1 but I do not know how to check whether it is the same version of PHP.

Comment: Just found the Health Check plug-in, this shows that the localhost is running PHP 5.3.5 and MySQL 5.5.9 whereas my web provider is using PHP 5.2.15 and MySQL 5.1.53. I have no idea if this makes a difference.

Comment: FWIW more info and a possible change in focus. Whilst trying various things on the local instance I see that *BOTH* instances show links in the form:  
http://bch.techzen.org/programme/?month=May,2011 

but only the local instance is able to read the $month variable.

Comment: Please add the code that actually generates the links! Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is in the strtotime function. With a permalink of _italic_http://bch.techzen.org/programme/?month=April,2011_italic_ when I echo $month (the parameter) I see "April,2011" (correct) but all date conversions, e.g. 

$firstday:

$lastday:

$prevmth: -2678400

$nextmth: 2678400

$prevlink: /programme?month=December,1969

$nextlnk: /programme?month=February,1970
<< January, 1970 >>

Comment: Ignore the comment above.  
I think the problem is in the strtotime function, particularly when using "the first day of" as a parameter. With a permalink of _http://bch.techzen.org/programme/?month=April,2011_ when I echo $month (the parameter) I see "April,2011" (correct) but all date conversions which depend on this are wrong, e.g. $firstday = strtotime("the first day of ".$month); is blank whilst $prevmth = strtotime("-1 month", $firstday); gives -2678400.

Comment: Not an answer as such, more a workaround.

Assuming that the problem lies in my webhost's version of PHP not understanding relative entries in strtotime correctly (possibly because of timezone settings) I have rewritten the code to pass parameter in format 04/2011, then in the receiving code prepend 01/, explode into an array and convert using mktime. Uglier, not as easy to read, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check if a **.htaccess** file exists on the web server and look for a rewriteRule. This could be the source of your messed up links!

Additionally go to 'Settings - Permalinks' in your wordpress backend and check if there is a difference at 'Common Settings'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Andre. The permalinks setings are identical (month & name) and so are the .HTACCESS files with the following code:

    # BEGIN WordPress  
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>  

# END WordPress    
ReWrite rules are new to me so no idea if any of these are a problem.

Comment: just another guess: did you probably put the '/' to the category slug (under 'Posts - Categories')?

Comment: Thanks again. In this case "programme" is a page not a category so no slug.